# Splitting a string from mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a variable from mysql database in this format:
631234567J56
and i want to display split it in php so that it will read like
63-1234567-J-56
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help with [certain problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [put some efforts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://www.google.com). Read [stack overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Use `substr`, then come again.

Comment: Thank you as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If lenght of string is fixed can you do this:

```
$string = "631234567J56";
$output = substr($string, 0, 2)."-".substr($string, 2, 7)."-".substr($string, 9, 1)."-".substr($string, 10, 2);

echo $output;
```